# Uploading a file to a blob container seems to leak channels

Tags: java, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure, and I am using azure-storage-blob v11.0.0 for java and trying to upload a file by following the sample here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-java-getting-started

This is upload as expected, but I my application is kept alive, there seems to be a remote socket timeout that will lead to generate and exception :

```
18:16:46.528 23751 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] INFO  com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.LoggingFactory$LoggingPolicy - Successfully Received Response
Request try:'1', request duration:'1271' ms, operation duration:'1271' ms
PUT: https://REDACTED.blob.core.windows.net/REDACTED/REDACTED.wav
Authorization: REDACTED
Content-Length: 275244
x-ms-version: 2018-11-09
x-ms-date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 16:16:45 GMT
host: REDACTED.blob.core.windows.net
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
connection: keep-alive
x-ms-client-request-id: c78bf188-f604-40da-b5a9-340eaad045bd
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
User-Agent:  Azure-Storage/11.0.0 (JavaJRE 1.8.0_212; Linux 4.19.49-1-MANJARO)

18:16:46.540 23763 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] DEBUG AzureCopy - Completed upload request. : 201
18:16:46.541 23764 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] DEBUG com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.SharedChannelPool - Channel released to pool: 77156491
18:19:48.496 205719 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] WARN  com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.NettyClient$AcquisitionListener - Error emitted on channel 8afa7171. Message: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant
18:19:48.500 205723 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.NettyClient$AcquisitionListener - Stack trace: 
java.lang.Exception: null
    at com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.NettyClient$AcquisitionListener.emitError(NettyClient.java:427)
    at com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.NettyClient$HttpClientInboundHandler.exceptionCaught(NettyClient.java:890)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:268)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:426)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:92)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:147)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:143)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.exceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:233)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:268)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.exceptionCaught(SslHandler.java:1098)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:268)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1375)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:174)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:682)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:617)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:534)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18:19:48.501 205724 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] INFO  com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.SharedChannelPool - ---- com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.SharedChannelPool@fbece82: size 768, keep alive (sec) 60 ----
18:19:48.502 205725 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] INFO  com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.SharedChannelPool - Channel    State   For Age URL
18:19:48.504 205727 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] INFO  com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.SharedChannelPool - 77156491   AVAIL   181s    182s    https://REDACTED.blob.core.windows.net:443
18:19:48.504 205727 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] INFO  com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.SharedChannelPool - 8afa7171   AVAIL   182s    182s    https://REDACTED.blob.core.windows.net:443
```

I can still use the application and perform other upload, but I am not really sure if I have to clean any unused connection of anything. Or if I can ignore these errors.

Edit : added code sample used

```
public class AzureCopy
{
    private final ContainerURL containerURL;

    public AzureCopy() throws InvalidKeyException, MalformedURLException
    {
        final String accountName = ConfHelper.getString("AZURE_ACCOUNT");
        final String accountKey = ConfHelper.getString("AZURE_KEY");

        final SharedKeyCredentials creds = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);

        final ServiceURL serviceURL = new ServiceURL(new URL("https://" + accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net"), StorageURL.createPipeline(creds, new PipelineOptions()));

        containerURL = serviceURL.createContainerURL(ConfHelper.getString("AZURE_CONTAINER"));
    }

    public void upload(final File toUpload)
    {
        if(toUpload != null)
        {
            final BlockBlobURL blobURL = containerURL.createBlockBlobURL(toUpload.getName());

            try
            {
                uploadFile(blobURL, toUpload);
            }
            catch(final IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void uploadFile(final BlockBlobURL blob, final File sourceFile) throws IOException
    {
        final AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(sourceFile.toPath());

        TransferManager.uploadFileToBlockBlob(fileChannel, blob, 8 * 1024 * 1024, null, null).subscribe(response -> System.out.println("Completed upload request. : " + response.response().statusCode()));
    }
}
```

As you can see this is mainly the sample code that is available on the github without the interactive menu. This class is instantiated at the start of the application, and the upload method is called when we need to upload a file. Nothing more. We don't create a new instance each time, we re-use the same instance when needed.

Comment: Could you show some necessary code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, sample code added